open path that exist doesnt work - python
The code gets the root path to the tests logs\log.jsonl which in the image is clearly there but cant open it

#doesnt work
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(dir_path, "logs\\log.jsonl"), 'r') as jsondata:
    data = json.load(jsondata)



with open("logs/log.jsonl, 'r') as jsondata:
    data = json.load(jsondata)


Please ignore the type of the image, after correcting, the error was still the same.

there is a typo in the extension of the file

Next time, please investigate the problem yourself first. SO should not be used to find typos.

Your code has jsnol instead of jsonl.  The O and N are swapped.

yes i corrected it but the error is still the same

Edit the question and add the full error message for the corrected code.

lol you have a typo.
The path in the code example is log.jsnol but in the fs it is log.jsonl
